# Can I build my own cymbal monkey traps?

Tags: fallout-4

One of the strangest traps in *Fallout 4* is the motion-sensitive cymbal monkey trap: a toy monkey that starts playing the cymbals when you get near it, with a trigger attached to it.

You can't pick these up, or disarm them for parts, or anything. But is there a way (possibly a mod) to make your own and set them up in your settlements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, I've never found a way to build these in the vanilla game.  They are used for traps as you said or alerting nearby enemies when you come across them in the Commonwealth. [The Wiki doesn't say you can build these either](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_traps#Clapping_cymbal_monkey).

I don't know if any mods exist for being able to make them, a quick Google search doesn't seem to yield any promising results.

Comment: The fact that they can only be disabled, but don't drop any items also indicates that they are non-craftable.

Answer (score 0):

I looked on nexus mod manager for fallout 4 , and I did find a mod that lets you create them

[Here](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6202/?) it is with a different skin then vanilla

Comment: does that mod let you create them, or just reskin the existing ones?

Comment: @KutuluMike I saw this mod as well, but I am pretty sure it's just a retexture of the monkey.